# Google Analytics Android track variable

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, analytics

I want Google Analytics to track a particular variable in my app.

So for instance, a variable 'a' has a separate value for every user of the app, is it possible for me to display the average(sum of the value of'a' held by every user/number of users) of the value of the variable in a Google Analytics dashboard ?

As per my understanding goes, we can do this using Custom Dimensions and Metrics.

Now as per my understanding , a custom metric value gets **added** to the current value and not updated as such. That too , I'm having trouble understanding **scope** of a custom metric.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also struggling to find any good example and advanced info on Custom Variables / Dimensions.

However to the problem you describe I would try a simpler approach. 
You can track event with its category, action, label. And also **value**.

Then, you'll have a category "ads", action "clicks", label "bannerA". And the value which could be any integer which will be represented as a sum of all values per total labels.

Example from Google Analytics dashboard if you set value 3 for each of those events: 
bannerA: 203 hits. Value 609. (203*3=609)

I'm not totally sure of this, so anybody with deeper knowledge and experience, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I used firebase to solve my problem. I suggest Firebase any day over GA for custom metrics

Comment: I have considered that approach as well. But it's very unclear when it comes to limits of free plan. If you track some variables on 50k concurrent users, what will happen with the free plan..

Comment: I don't see any limitation on the number of users. Is it mentioned somewhere by Google ?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood you. I was speaking about Firebase Realtime Database to send custom stuff. But that has 100 concurrent connections limit in free plan. Now I realize you're speaking about Firebase Analytics, so I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: I was speaking about Firebase realtime databases itself. Concurrency isn't a huge issue in my app. So i guess that's fine. Because Firebase requests are in pipeline , small delays don't matter I guess - at least for what i'm using it for